# Example of absolute continuous function that is not in $H^1$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Consider functions on $D=[C_1,C_2]$ with real $C_1<C_2$. Could somebody please give me an example function that is absolutely continuous on D but is not in $H^1$? Many thanks!

Comment: what is H1???????

Comment: Sorry for the typesetting. $H1$ is the usual $H^1[C_1,C_2]=W^{1,2}[C_1,C_2]$ Sobolev space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog $[C_1,C_2] = [0,1]$.

Let $u(x) = \int f(x) \, dx$ where $f \in L^1 \setminus L^2$.  For example, $f(x) = \tfrac12 x^{-1/2}$ gives you $u(x) = \sqrt x$.